# How to attach web project to process "MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe" (Microsoft Edge) automatically on start debugging in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, microsoft-edge, javascript-debugger, attach-to-process, script-debugging

as I just updated to Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015, I am facing the problem described in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346833/visual-studio-integrated-javascript-debugging-with-windows-10-edge) and correctly answered by Shaun Luttin.

In addition to that question I want to ask how this procedure can be automatically executed.

To be clear, I would like Visual Studio 2015 to act like debugging the projects in IE when selecting Edge, meaning open a browser tab/window and attach that process on starting debug to handle the server-side and client-side code in VS.

As a supplement, maybe someone can explain if that behaviour is desired or a bug or something else.

Comment: This might work for you: http://entrian.com/attach/

Comment: What is the problem in your environment? The debug symbols are not loading?

Comment: The current situation is, that this "Client Side Debugging in Visual Studio"-feature has been included to VS2017 for Chrome and will included for Edge (and Firefox) someday. See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The [Visual Studio 15.7.0 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#Edge) now provides the feature described in this question. The Windows 10 April 2018 Update is also needed, as it contains the [Microsoft Edge DevTools Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-protocol/0.1/).