# How to use Edge as default browser with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I added Edge as my default debug browser in VS 2013, but when try to run nothing happens.
Build succeeded and it says ready, but the browser doesnt display anything.
It may be useful to know I'm using VS 2013 Professional and Windows 10 Home Edition, 64 bits. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not much reason to assume it *should* work.  [This Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346833/visual-studio-integrated-javascript-debugging-with-windows-10-edge) proposes a workaround.

Comment: When you say "nothing happens," does that include the browser not opening or just that the browser displays nothing?

Comment: The browser doesnt even open, and if it is open already it displays nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, the browser displays properly after doing either of the following. I am also using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2013.

## Method 1

1. Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs > Set Default Programs
2. Find Microsoft Edge.
3. Choose "Set this program as default."

[image: Set Microsoft Edge as default.]

## Method 2

1. Settings > Default apps > Web browser
2. Choose Microsoft Edge.

[image: Settings > System > Web browser > Microsoft Edge]

In either case, Visual Studio 2013 will now debug in Microsoft Edge.