# Visual Studio (2022) javascript debugging not working with Edge browser

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Using Visual Studio 2022 v17.1.3 and Microsoft Edge 99.0.1150.55

I was using Chrome to execute my ASP.NET projects and Javascript breakpoints worked.  After switching to Edge, Javascript debugging stopped working.

I've followed suggestions in several stack articles, specifically this one with no results:

[Visual Studio integrated Javascript debugging with Windows 10 Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346833/visual-studio-integrated-javascript-debugging-with-windows-10-edge)

My settings are all configured properly:

[image]

Options->Debugging->General

[image]

Project Properties

[image]

Does anybody have an updated 2022 fix for this?

Comment: I have the same issue with chrome on 17.2.4

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until today. The solution for me and i think also for all of mankind is :-) to run your application not under the "Default Website" on IIS (Internet Information System). Your application must be configurated as a own Site with own Port on IIS. Here are some screenshots as example:

Configuration in IIS:

[IIS Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL7hp.png)

Configuration in Visual Studio for your "Start Project":

[VS Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyprS.png)

Configuration in Visual Studio Code:

[VS Code Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR01F.png)

I hope i could help all of you to solve the problem ;-)